# Does it matter from which country i buy New iphone?

Tags: iphone

I originally live in Europe but for study purposes i'm staying in Seoul, South Korea for 6 months, i want to buy the new iPhone 11 pro from here and i don't want to wait until i go back to Europe. Does it matter from which country i buy the phone from, or is there any differences in any case, regulation wise or product wise. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I buy an iPhone 4 in another country?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7006/can-i-buy-an-iphone-4-in-another-country)

Comment: Apple's guarantee structure is unclear. You can certainly get warranty service in the country in which you buy the phone (assuming it's a new phone bought from Apple); you may have trouble doing so in another country.

Comment: @fsb iPhone technology has changed a lot since iPhone 4.  Would the answer still be the same?

Comment: The other question focuses on keyboard.  Your question is very open-ended and risks being closed (see [ask] for tips on asking good questions).  If you get more specific about what you're concerned about, and you've already performed research on Apple's site and still don't have an answer, you can [edit] your question to add that additional info.

Comment: I bought an iPad in the US and use it in Europe. When I [check its warranty](https://checkcoverage.apple.com), it does not have the 24 month warranty as required in the EU.